# Android Equalizer for API Level < 9

Tags: android, java-native-interface, media, equalizer

I'm looking for a way to use an equalizer within my app which does not rely on the
android.media.audiofx package especially android.media.audiofx. Equalizer class because these are only available for api level > 9.

Does anybody know about native libraries which work well under android? I've found mpg123 but it seems that this library is very slow. Or is there even another way to implement an equalizer without native librarys?

Comment: Hi if you get solution ,tell me how ?

Comment: sadly I did not find any solution as pheonixblade posted there seems to be no good way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did quite a bit of research on this and found that you would have to likely rewrite the entire AudioTrack library in order to accomplish this.

It would require heavy DSP which would be best accomplished using the NDK, if you really want to do it.

Otherwise, I would just write a wrapper that tells the application which API level you're in, and disable those features.

Here is the abstract I wrote on this problem:

[http://isthisonthetest.com/?q=node/12](https://web.archive.org/web/20150214143130/http://isthisonthetest.com/?q=node/12)

Hope this helps!

EDIT:

This link has been getting a few hits (and the link was broken), so I redirected it to a blog post I just made with the original text.  The URL above should work now.